# python issues with KeyError: skip over errors when data is not in the json?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, textbox

One is having trouble with a basic Python script that calls an API and then displays the info on a simple textbox. The issue is that sometimes, the Application Programming Interface (API) will have all the information, and sometimes it will not. When it has all the information, the script completes perfectly and displays all the information as laid out; however, sometimes the API does not have a specific section in it, which then causes a KeyError.

It is either required to completely skip over the area if that section is not in the API or preferably have a text that sits there and says "no info" and if the API has that section, it should be out.

Below is the script:

```
  data = {'name': 'Kev', 'connected': 'ONLINE', 'time': '2024-03-03T23:01:00Z', 'up-loader': [{'uploaded': 'Yes', 'upload-time': '2024-03-03T18:01:00Z'}]}

    # Main Info - allways in the json
  InfoNAME = data["name"]
  InfoCONN = data["connected"]
  InfoTIME = data["time"]
    # This info is only in the json sometimes - here is where the problem is
  InfoUPLOAD = data['up-loader'][0]["uploaded"]
  InfoUPTIME = data['up-loader'][0]["upload-time"] 

# Take info from above and load it onto the chart below
    # deletes all the text that is currently in the TextBox 
  text_box.delete('1.0', END)   
    # insert new data into the TextBox
# Name
  text_box.insert(END, "Name:  ")
  text_box.insert(END, InfoNAME)
# Online status  
  text_box.insert(END, "Status: ")
  text_box.insert(END, InfoCONN)
# Last online Time  
  text_box.insert(END, "Last Online: ")
  text_box.insert(END, InfoTIME)
# Upload logger
  text_box.insert(END, "Was there an upload:")  
  text_box.insert(END, InfoUPLOAD)
# Upload time
  text_box.insert(END, "When was the upload: ")
  text_box.insert(END, InfoUPTIME)
```

I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Ideally, [edit] the question with examples of JSON that works and doesn’t work. Reduce your code to a [mcve] that focuses on the problem (load the JSON and extract data) and leave out everything else (like Tkinter code).

Comment: good idea, I've been through and cut out all the unnecessary stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

You can specifically check if the key is present by using the `in` keyword:

```
if somekey in mydata:
    # yes it is present, so it is safe to
    # access mydata['somekey']
```

Or you can use the `.get()` function, which allows you to supply a default value to use if the key is not found:

```
value = mydata.get(somekey, 'Oops this was not found')
```

Comment: So something like this...

  InfoUPLOAD = data.get(['up-loader'][0]["uploaded"] , 'Oops this was not found')

when i try that i get a TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

how would i work in option one into the script?

Comment: No, it would be `data['up-loader'][0].get('uploaded', 'Oops ...')`

Comment: sort of worked, it worked great for normal ones when i did   
InfoCONN = data.get('connected', No connection info found') 
but when i went to do the one i need data['up-loader'][0].get('uploaded', 'Oops ...') it did not work, to make it work i had to do data.get('up-loader''0''uploaded', 'Oops ...') which worked great, until i tested it on a response json that contained the info that i needed to get, in that case it still came back as Oops ...

any idea what is the next step?

Comment: I can't answer unless you show the exact code and the exact json data.  Otherwise it is too hard to guess exactly what you did.

Comment: `API.json is...
{'name': 'Kev', 'connected': 'ONLINE', 'time': '2024-03-03T23:01:00Z', 'up-loader': [{'uploaded': 'Yes', 'upload-time': '2024-03-03T18:01:00Z'}]}
`



and the misbehaving code is `InfoUPTIME = data.get('up-loader''0''upload-time', 'No Recorded Time')` sorry for the bad formatting here, Im still trying to get my head around how to comment here

Comment: `'up-loader''0''upload-time'` makes no sense, because that's just a bunch of strings smashed together.

Comment: I think you meant `data['up-loader'][0].get('upload-time', 'No Recorded Time')`

Comment: that works great when the json `'up-loader': [{'uploaded': 'Yes', etc etc` line is in the json but when it is not in the json i get a `KeyError: 'up-loader` basically back to the start, for some reason the API that i pull the json data off of just completely omits that area of the result if there was no uploader events

Comment: So it seems that you need to use the first option in my answer for at least part of your solution.  `if 'up-loader' in data:`

Comment: nailed it, that was the missing piece! i had placed it in the wrong place at first and so it hadn't worked, second time is a charm, not only has it solved my issue its let me customized information on the page depending on results, thank you so much! i massively appreciate it, much happy :) ill add it to the answer box!

Answer (score 0):

```py
if somekey in mydata:
```

worked perfectly and meant i could not only cut out the error but i could go through and customize what text was displayed when and where, max stoked. code is as below

i also used `.get('name', 'No Name Recorded')` for some parts, but the real winner was `if somekey in mydata:`

```py
data = {'name': 'Kev', 
        'connected': 'ONLINE', 
        'time': '2024-03-03T23:01:00Z',
        'up-loader': [{'uploaded': 'Yes', 
                       'upload-time': '2024-03-03T18:01:00Z'}]}

# Main Info - always in the json
InfoNAME = data.get('name', 'No Name Recorded')
InfoCONN = data["connected"]
InfoTIME = data["time"]

# CODE THAT FIXED ISSUE BELOW
if 'up-loader' in data:
    InfoUPLOAD = data['up-loader'][0]["uploaded"]
    InfoUPTIME = data['up-loader'][0]["upload-time"]

# Take info from above and load it onto the chart below  
# deletes all the text that is currently in the TextBox
text_box.delete('1.0', END)

# Insert new data into the TextBox
# Name
text_box.insert(END, "Name:  ")
text_box.insert(END, InfoNAME)
# Online status
text_box.insert(END, "Status: ")
text_box.insert(END, InfoCONN)
# Last online Time
text_box.insert(END, "Last Online: ")
text_box.insert(END, InfoTIME)

# Upload logger
if 'up-loader' in data:
    text_box.insert(END, "Was there an upload:")
    text_box.insert(END, InfoUPLOAD)
    text_box.insert(END, "When was the upload: ")
    text_box.insert(END, InfoUPTIME)
```