# Ignore or replace 'KeyError' in 'csv_file.writerow' - Python

Tags: python, csv, keyerror

I am working on a Python script that pulls data from an API, turns it to a JSON then goes through and writes a row to a CSV file for a small database, it writes a new row for each of the devices in the JSON, for as many entries as there are in the JSON, somewhere between 10 and 100 it is running great and doing as expected until it hits a field without an entry in it. it then throws a key error.

I would like to either skip the missing field completely (while still writing the rest of the row) or replace the missing field with "N/A" or "NaN" or "No data" or something like that. i have tried a few things from here but I'm either googling the wrong thing or not finding the answer for my problem

Heres the code:

```
JSON_Temp.json --->   {"numFound": 5, "devices": [
{"general": {"mac": "M1033770383",}, "network": {"gateway": 542, "downRssi": -110, "upRssi": -124}, "reading": {"connectivity": "ONLINE"}}, 
{"general": {"mac": "A1007634388",}, "network": {"downRssi": -110, "upRssi": -124}, "reading": {"connectivity": "OFFLINE"}},
{"general": {"mac": "C1031474373",}, "network": {"gateway": 533, "downRssi": -110, "upRssi": -124}}]}

--------------------------------------------------------
import csv
import json

with open("CSV Builder/JSON_Temp.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

fname = "CSV Builder/DeviceReport.csv"
with open(fname, "w", newline="") as file:
   csv_file = csv.writer(file)
   csv_file.writerow(['MAC',
                      'Gateway',
                      'Connectivity',
                      'Down_RSSI',
                      'Up_RSSI',
                      ])

   for item in data["devices"]:
     csv_file.writerow([item['general']['mac'], 
                        item['network']['gateway'],
                        item['reading']['connectivity'],
                        item['network']['downRssi'],
                        item['network']['upRssi'],
                    ])

     print('done')
```

Comment: Use `.get()` and provide a default value.  `item['network'].get('gateway', 'N/A')`  And didn't I already [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78098927/494134) a nearly identical question from you?  Why are you asking essentially the same question again?

Comment: This is not valid JSON, because of extra comma, e.g.`{"mac": "M1033770383",}`

Comment: @John Gordon you sort of did, your response to the previous question was the first thing i turned to when this issue came up, how ever i couldn't get it to work, turns out that i was putting the .get in the wrong place the whole time! i was doing `item.get['general']['mac'],` instead of `item['location'].get('address', 'N/A')` an absolute rookie mistake, but then at this stage i am a rookie at this stuff, i didn't realize what i was doing wrong, I've gone through and tested each and they are working prefect! huge learning moment there, thank you endlessly for you help!!!

Comment: There are easier ways without installing a third-party package, but I would still recommend `pydash`, as it makes your code clean and readable when fetching nested key values. If a key at any depth does not exist, pydash handles it pretty well. `item['general']['mac']` -> `pydash.get(item, "general.mac", "N/A")`

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm wondering if you can help me out again. this is not worthy a new question, i thought i would just ask here, I've spent the morning trying to figure it out but i cant seem to get it, my question in, using .get how do i  get "food1" in the following `{"general": {"Fname": "Molly", "Lname": "Malone"}, "specific": {"City": "Dublin", "job": "fishmonger", "Sells": [{"food1": "Cockles", "food2": "mussels"}]}},`i can .get any other data in json this is from, but for some reason i cant get food1 or food2, i know it will be something small but I'm stumped, using `item[specific].get()`

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the actual strings "food1" and "food2", or do you mean you want to get the strings "Cockels" and "mussels"?

Comment: the strings "Cockels" and "mussels" please, individually though not together, i need to add each to its own line - just to clarify, there will be many different food1 and food 2 results in the json file, i need to get each one for textbox and .csv etc